# Jenkins :- Pending upstream "Job Name" in build queue

Tags: jenkins

I have a jenkins projects as below

Upstream project (A) --> Post Build Task of Project A calls  -->  Project B --> Post build Task of Project B calls --> Project C.

I can see this relation on the "dependency graph"

Project A completes in 30 minutes
Project B completes in 2 hours,
Project C completes in 2 hours,

I enabled "Build periodically" in project "A" for every 40 minutes.

This cause the Project 'C" to stay in queue with error as

Pending upstream "Project A" in build queue

Is there a solution to execute "Project C" with out dependent of project A status.

Answer (score 1):

You should try the [Build Flow plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) and create a new job with this build flow:

```
build("Project A")
build("Project B")
build("Project C")
```

Schedule this new job every 40 minutes, it should do the job :) (with no queuing problem)

Another solution if you are using Maven jobs, please uncheck the second option (in the Maven build step):

[image]

Comment: HI Bruno Lavit, Thanks a lot for your reply, Is there a way to edit the "post build task" to perform this job, because we deployed lot of jobs .By "Build Flow Plugin " we need to change the design itself.

Comment: The build flow plugin is more flexible compare to the upstream/downstream actions in the Jenkins jobs. I've updated my post with another solution.